# Android WebView - Choosing a file via html form

Tags: android, html, facebook, forms, webview

i have a web app/Facebook app with a form that requires a user to upload an image. When accessing the site via the Facebook app on android devices, the choose file dialog will not prompt for the file location.

This only happens when using the native WebView from the Facebook app.  If I choose to use an external browser (chrome or otherwise) the form works properly. Anyone know a if there is a workaround?

Comment: I wish it was as easy as enabling JavaScript.